# Installing Wordpress on Windows 8 using XAMPP but PHP not running

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I'm Windows 8 user who wants to install Wordpress.

I'm using `XAMPP` and have checked that my XAMPP is working. I also have created a database on MySql and set up the `wp-config.php` with the database details I have created before.
But every time I click the wp-admin/install.php, I get this error :

> Error: PHP is not running
>       WordPress requires that your web server is running PHP. Your server does not have PHP installed, or PHP is turned off.

I'm using mySQL database, and database name is wordpress. 
This is my config :

> // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
>   /** The name of the database for WordPress */ define('DB_NAME',
>   'wordpress');
>
> /** MySQL database username */ define('DB_USER', 'root');
>
> /** MySQL database password */ define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
>
> /** MySQL hostname */ define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
>
> /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
>   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
>
> /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
>   define('DB_COLLATE', '');

I still get the error, need some help.

Comment: `WordPress requires that your web server is running PHP. Your server does not have PHP installed, or PHP is turned off.` is pretty clear though, isn't it?

Comment: Try running any simple php file and check if that works or not ?

Comment: **Error:** says it all. Start PHP (by starting WAMP) and try to execute simple php statement `echo "Tested!!! PHP is working fine!!!";`

Comment: I've tried and php is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XAMPP controle panel to start Apache (PHP) and MySQL. Every time when you shutdown windows Apache and MySQL will be shutdown as well. If you haven't setup Apache (PHP) and MySQL as a service you need to manually start apache(PHP) and MySQL via the controle panel. **C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe** if you use the default directory. Make sure to run the programm as admin.

Comment: Did you need to restart Apache and MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

Go and check C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf if php module is loaded or if this line exist *Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"*. 
If not then add this line: Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf", but before go and check if this file exists.
If this file doesn't exists then add this line to httpd.conf: **LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_2.dll"**

Open CMD and exec this command:

**c:\xampp\apache_start.bat**

Output of this command will show error, why the apache doesn't start, if it doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.  I followed everything in the directions to a "tee."  But at the very end, I went to the wordpress/wp-admin/install.php file and opened it; that is where I got the "Error: PHP is not running" message.

But then I went and entered the path

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php
```

in my browswer's address bar and it worked!  Silly of me not to do that at first, but hopefully this answer will help some of you out there.